# Tomcat create always new session

Tags: java, session, tomcat6

I created some web application, on Tomcat 6. When I am accessing via localhost to these machine everything work good - server create one session. But when I connect to this application via Internet, Tomcat creates each time 3 new sessions. Do anyone knows why? The clue could be, that Tomcat server is in DMZ zone, so when i connect via proxy, or from localhost everything is good, but when I access via Internet, the problem occure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem, the session time out was caused by the network settings. There were 2 problems: 1) mess up with ports connection between tomcat, apache and DNS server (different ports were set up for one application on each machines)
2) When I was connecting via LAN to app, tomcat was creating 1 session and everything was ok. But when I was connecting via Internet tomcat created as I said 3 different session - the first one was exactly like in LAN connection case (session was containing SESIONID for application), but 2,3 was created in the same time and their were empty sessions. My internet adress for application was like: www.example.com/application. In tomcat documentation I read that in this case I should set up emptySessionPath in server access configuration. 
When I done everything that I wrote before, my application started to work properly. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I faced with a similar problem and after setting emptySessionPath on "true" everything work fine!